# Maven antrun plugin missing target task after combining from multiple profiles

Tags: maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

This is quite an interesting problem I have 2 profiles as defined below. I'm using Maven 3.6.3 with the latest Java 11.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>assembly-unzip</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>          
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <target>
                  <unzip src="src1.zip" dest="dest10" />
                  <copy  file="copy1.txt" todir="dest11"/>
                </target>
              </configuration>              
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>   
  <profile>
    <id>assembly-get</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <target>
                  <mkdir dir="download" />
                  <get src="src20" dest="dest"/>
                  <unzip src="dest/src20}" dest="dest"/>
                  <get src="src21" dest="dest"/>
                  <unzip src="dest/src21}" dest="dest"/>                  
                </target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>        
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>     
</profiles>
```

When I activate BOTH profiles, I get from (-X) that Maven combines the 2 antrun plugin configurations into a single configuration that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <exportAntProperties default-value="false"/>
  <failOnError default-value="true"/>
  <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
  <mavenProject default-value="${project}"/>
  <pluginArtifacts>${plugin.artifacts}</pluginArtifacts>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${maven.antrun.skip}</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <target>
    <mkdir dir="download"/>
    <get src="src20" dest="dest"/>
    <unzip src="dest/src20}" dest="dest"/>
    <get src="src21" dest="dest"/>
    <unzip src="dest/src21}" dest="dest"/>
    <copy  file="copy1.txt" todir="dest11"/>
  </target>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
  <versionsPropertyName default-value="maven.project.dependencies.versions"/>
</configuration>
```

What's missing from the combined configuration is:

```
<unzip src="src1.zip" dest="dest10" />
```

I've tried this multiple times in different ways and the long and short of it is that it seems like if the  from the 1st profile that Maven processes has an  task (for example) then any  tasks in the  of the 2nd profile will be ignored and NOT part of the combined configuration. Please be aware that i'm just using  as an example. I've tried it with other tasks and see the same behavior.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Use an `<id>` to each of your execution: without it, you get the default, and that's what maven use to determine duplicate configuration items when it merge them.
2. Use combine.children and so on. I would advise you not to do that, but you may read more on [blog.sonatype.com](https://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/) or at [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#advanced_configuration_inheritance).

You could also directly use the power of `ant`, create target and invoke it conditionally using [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. Then the other think to remember is the order in which they appear in the POM is the order in which they are evaluated. So this answered my question. Thanks again.

Comment: There is an additional problem with ordering multiple plugins within different profiles all attached to the same lifecycle phase. Apparently this is an old bug and it doesn't seem to be adequately addressed. So I had to attach plugins to different lifecycle phases to have a correct orderly run.

Comment: I don't see the problem. For me Maven order thing by order of declaration.

Comment: "Maven order thing by order of declaration" unfortunately this is not the case.